# Index with hyperreference to the page

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I would like to have hyperlink in the index list, like if I press the page 8 it will move me to the page 8.

I use the package

```
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
```

where `[xindy]` makes it in alphabetical order. Here is for my hyperlinks

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Alessandro Lin}
}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about how you make the index and the `hyperref` setting. It would be better if you provide a MWE.

Comment: Teddy has asked you for a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) not only some code snippets. And because the shown settings already produce links in the Index (see my edited answer), is seems you are still not showing the root of your problem. So please read the page, I've linked in this comment and show a real working example, that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use packages [`imakeidx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) and [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to get the page links automatically:

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\par\\penalty-50\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}\\par\\nobreak"
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options={-s \jobname.ist}]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{5}
Parity\index{Parity}
\newpage\mbox{}\newpage\mbox{}\newpage
Acquaintances\index{Acquaintances}
Coprime\index{Coprime}
lattice\index{lattice}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Index with page links]

Note: The red frames are only shown in PDF-viewers, they will not be printed. `hyperref` also provides options to use underlining or colored links instead of frames or to not visualize the links. See the manual for more information.

---

Edit: With the settings you've shown in your edited question, your also already get links in the index:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}% Note: With xindy you have to run pdflatex with option --shell-escape. See section 4 of the imakeidx manual.
\makeindex
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% Option hidelinks does not make much sense, because the options set by \hyperset below will overwrite it.
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Alessandro Lin}
}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{5}
Parity\index{Parity}
\newpage\mbox{}\newpage\mbox{}\newpage
Acquaintances\index{Acquaintances}
Coprime\index{Coprime}
lattice\index{lattice}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: with imakeidx and xindy]

Comment: Nice. What does filecontents do, why is it required? Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO The `filecontents` environment writes the index style file, that is used by `imakeidx` via `options={-s \jobname.ist}`. It activates the letter headings in the index. See the MakeIndex manual for more information about index style files.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yeah, it did not work before because I have put `\makeindex`after 
`\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} ` now is working thanks!

Comment: @AlessandroLin My example would also work with `\makeindex` after `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`. You just have to load `hyperref` after `imakeidx`. `hyperref` should always be loaded after other packages except if the manual of `hyperref` or the other package explicitly says something else.